# Java switch connection when connection error occured (Failover connection)

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, sqlconnection, ojdbc

Is it possible switch to second connection source with JAVA when sql connection error occured ?

```
 protected Connection dbConnect(String jdbcProvider) throws 
    MbException,SQLException{
       return getJDBCType4Connection(jdbcProvider,JDBC_TransactionType.MB_TRANSACTION_AUTO);
}


protected Connection dbStandByConnect(String jdbcProvider,String jdbcProvider2) throws MbException{

    Connection con=null;        
    try {
        con= dbConnect(jdbcProvider);
    } catch (SQLException e) { 
        try {
            con= dbConnect(jdbcProvider2);
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sqlEx); 
        }
    }
    return con;
}
```

I have no idea if it is right way or not ? Do you have any suggestions as to how I can make this work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a connection pool or driver that does the failover for you. Other than that your question is too broad and unclear.

Comment: Thank you for comment, actually it is very simple what I want.I just want to use secondary db when first connection is failed.

Comment: If you are using Oracle (which your use of the tag `ojdbc` suggests), then why not use the features that Oracle provides for failover. And again, this may sound 'simple', but it really isn't and solution depend on your exact needs and what your application can or cannot accept, etc.

Comment: I have alreay add failover=on  but I need to learn how java side must be ?